# Regenerate thumbnails unexpected resolution (96 x 96)

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, wp-cli

I'm using WP CLI `wp media regenerate` to resize my thumbnails.

I've noticed something a bit weird. The original image I upload is a JPEG with a resolution (DPI) of 72. The images that are generated have a resolution of 96.

Is this something WordPress core is doing?

Here's what I'm seeing via **Tools** > **Site Health** > **Media Handling**

[image: WordPress Site Health Media Handling]

Here are the image sizes defined via **Settings** > **Media**

- Thumbnail: 150 x 150
- Medium Size: 300 x 300
- Large Size: 1200 x 668

And then via my functions, I have the following image sizes defined:

```
function mytheme_add_custom_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size('landscape-large-1x', 600, 334, true);
    add_image_size('landscape-large-2x', 1200, 668, true); // Largest image available
    add_image_size('landscape-medium-1x', 450, 251, true);
    add_image_size('landscape-medium-2x', 900, 502, true);
    add_image_size('landscape-small-1x', 384, 214, true);
    add_image_size('landscape-small-2x', 768, 428, true);
    add_image_size('landscape-smallest-1x', 324, 180, true);
    add_image_size('landscape-smallest-2x', 648, 360, true);
    add_image_size('square-1x', 96, 96, true); 
    add_image_size('square-2x', 192, 192, true);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_custom_image_sizes');
```

It's also worth mentioning, that I have the following image adjustments via functions.php:

```
/**
 * Remove srcset width limitation
 */
function mytheme_remove_max_srcset_image_width($max_width) {
    return false;
}
add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', 'mytheme_remove_max_srcset_image_width');

/**
 * Remove default images sizes
 */
function mytheme_remove_default_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['1536x1536']); // Introduced in WP 5.3
    unset($sizes['2048x2048']); // Introduced in WP 5.3
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'mytheme_remove_default_image_sizes');

/**
 * Remove large "scaled" images
 */
add_filter('big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false');
```

Comment: what size is your thumbnail set to in settings? It sounds like the upscaling is what was unexpected, would I be right?

Comment: Hey @TomJNowell, I've updated my question with the image size information.

Comment: Are you sure the original image's DPI was 72 and not 96 (or perhaps the DPI was *not* explicitly set, hence the default which might be 96 in your case, was then used)? You could also check if there are any plugins or custom code which might be changing the active image editor class - see the [`wp_image_editors` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_image_editors/). And I said so because with GD (where the image editor class is `WP_Image_Editor_GD`), the default image DPI is 96.

Comment: ...so even if the original image DPI was 72, 300, etc., images created/manipulated using GD would always have a 96 DPI - i.e. the original DPI (except for 96) is not preserved by default.

Comment: Hey, @Sam, have you managed to sort this out already or is it still an ongoing mystery? Could you provide us with a link to the problematic image, so that we could try to fiddle with it?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback SallyCJ and following up vlood. The original image was definitely set to 72DPI. Regeneration took place initially via my local environment [(DevKinsta)](https://kinsta.com/devkinsta). When I performed regeneration via staging, the DPI corrected itself to 72.